# Assign a return value in Task<String> HttpClient Async to another variable

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm stuck at casting my return value in a Tast Async function to another variable.

```
           using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foo.com");
            await GetSecret(client);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<String> GetSecret(HttpClient client)
    {
        //JArray results = new JArray();
        string url = $"/strkey?api-version=2016-10-01";

        using (var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responsContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject password = JObject.Parse(responsContent);
            string ip = password["value"].ToString();
            return ip;
        }
    }
```

How can I assign the value of **ip** to out of the function? For example I want something like below:

```
public class objA
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public objA(string ip)
    {
        key = ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `new objA(await TestAsync.GetSecret(httpClient))`?

Comment: Even though HttpClient implements IDisposable, you shouldn't put it within a using statement. See [this article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). I suggest you use another library that wraps it or otherwise doesn't suffer from this flaw, such as [Flurl.Http](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your await Task returns a string which is ip, you can just easily call to the previous method as below.

```
static async Task yourMethod(HttpClient client)
        {
            var obj = await GetSecret(client);
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

declare a variable outside of the using scope where you call HttpClient

```
    public void MethodName()
    {
        var returnedIp = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foo.com");
            returnedIp = await GetSecret(client);
        }
    }
```

As has been pointed out above in a comment, you should not use the HttpClient in the way you are, but I have answered your question with out a change to the code you are currently using

Comment: I don't really understand your point. I want to assign the value of ip.